# Installing Android Studio on Mac for the first time, but getting "IDE Already Running” error

Tags: android-studio

I am new to this - I trying to install Android Studio on my MacBook Air (macOS Mojave v10.14.6). After the installing, when I try and open Android Studio I get the following error:

Cannot connect to already running IDE instance. CannotActivateException: /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2023.1

When trying to find the folder directory above, I cannot find /Google/ in the Application Support folder - not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Check what access rights you have on that directory. You may have installed a Google related application before as 'root' causing the owner status of the directory to become 'root', and that would stop you from accessing the directory as a regular user.
If the Google directory has got owner 'root' then run this command.

sudo chown -R your_user_name:desired_group_name ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google

Answer (score 0):

sudo chown -R your_user_name:group_name ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google

your primary group name is staff

you can get your username and groupname with ‘id’ command in terminal like this

[view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbsFA.png)

uid=501(erdemakca) gid=20(staff)

and you can type like this with this results

sudo chown -R erdemakca:staff ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google